# Is TR2 Going to be Released in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++11, tr1, c++17, c++-tr2

There is lots of sweet stuff in [TR2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#Technical_Report_2). Is that going to be in [C++17](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17)?

I understand that TR1 was completed in 2005 and had to wait until C++11 to be standardized.
But I also understand that TR2 is already complete?

My link to C++17 doesn't mention anything about TR2, but I am hoping...

Comment: Note that TR2 isn't actually a thing any more, these enhancements are all coming to us separate.

Comment: http://isocpp.org/std/status

Comment: @CoryNelson Meaning they won't be incorporated into an official standard until C++17 or what? I mean we already have many of them in Boost, just not in C++ proper.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That information would make a great answer. +1 to your comment.

Comment: For a thorough explanation of the process, as well as current status (as of ~mid September), see Alisdair Meredith's talk from CppCon 2014, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo-WpGkb2JM). (edit: link corrected)

Comment: Also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe.

The point of TR (and now technical specifications) is to allow something to mature independent of the standard iteration process.  They can publish a TS, see how it works, see if there are any problems in the implementation and/or use of the feature, and if everything works they can then "fold" it into the full standard.

Each TS is considered on its own merits to see if it will be folded into the next standard.

See http://isocpp.org/std/status (thanks @BenjaminLindley) for current status of the Technical Specification working groups.

Any of them, if completed well prior to 2017, could be folded into the standard.  It is unlikely they all will be.

A goal is that we can get the `std::experimental` features to play with (and use if we are willing to accept the ground shifting under our feet) earlier, while having the features once added to `std` with fewer regrets and specification changes after that point.  There are probably also massive organizational overhead advantages to decoupling the main line standard from each of these side projects and allowing them to evolve independently.

Comment: Fascinating. Is there any documentation on the Testing one of these TSs must undergo to be accepted? Or is that more of an arbitrary, committee chooses type thing?

Comment: @JonathanMee I am not aware of such.

Comment: @JonathanMee: "Industry consensus" would be a fair summary. Anyone who takes the time to write a paper with a well-argued opinion can expect that to read and weighted.

Comment: @Yakk My question has been turned on it's ear a bit. I guess I'd really like to know what it takes to get these TSs out of `std::experimental` and into `std`. Does that happen outside of a standard release?

Comment: @JonathanMee Exactly what it takes to get anything else into `std`, except that there will already be a body of implementation experience to help make the decision.

Comment: @JonathanMee And the mere fact that a proposal has already passed the TS process is an indication that it's more likely to be accepted by the full committee.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of a Technical Report, or Technical Specification as they are now, is to gain implementation experience and feedback from implementors and users, to better assess the suitability of features for standardization. One would need a crystal ball to know if a particular TS will be included in a future standard, and which future standard that might be.

[Version 1 of the Library Fundamentals TS](https://rawgit.com/cplusplus/fundamentals-ts/v1/fundamentals-ts.html) appears to have passed its final ballot at the November 2014 committee meeting, and version 2 is currently being drafted to incorporate feedback and new proposals. This means it is getting closer to being something which implementors and industry users are happy with, and version 1 is now an immutable specification which implementors can choose to conform to. It is still more than possible for later versions, and later standards, to change in ways which would be incompatible with version 1.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list (from your wikipedia link) of the features of TR2 - and *my comments*:

- Threads - *Included in C++11*
- The Asio C++ library - *this is being considered for a future C++ standard*
- Signals/Slots - *no action at this time (that I know of)*
- Filesystem Library - *FileSystem Technical Specification*
- Boost Any Library - *Part of the Library Fundamentals Technical Specification*
- Lexical Conversion Library - *no action at this time (that I know of)*
- New String Algorithms - *no action at this time (that I know of)*
- Toward a More Complete Taxonomy of Algebraic Properties for Numeric Libraries in TR2 - *no action at this time (that I know of)*
- Adding heterogeneous comparison lookup to associative containers for TR2 - * Included in C++14*