# clang++ cannot initialize a variable of type 'int(*)[dim2]' with an rvalue of type 'int (*)[dim2]'

Tags: c++

Why does the code

```
void fcn(int *twoDArrayPtr, const int dim1, const int dim2) {
    int (*array)[dim2] = reinterpret_cast<int (*)[dim2]>(twoDArrayPtr);
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

generate the compiler error

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int (*)[dim2]' with
  an rvalue of type 'int (*)[dim2]'
```

The types are the same, so I'd think the assignment can be performed.  Since `int (*)[dim2]` is a pointer to an array of size `dim2` and as such could be a pointer to a bunch of arrays of size `dim2` in contiguous memory indexable by the pointer, I would think this should work.

I'm using clang++ on Mac OS/X with the following version information:

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: This works on Linux with Gnu `g++`, just not on Mac OS/X... is there some compiler directive that will help?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd get that particular error, but the size of an array must be a constant expression, which `dim2` isn't. (Except with GCC, which supports variable-length arrays in some circumstances as a non-standard extension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dim2` is not a compile-time constant, and VLAs (variable-length arrays) don't exist in C++. Some other compilers (such as gcc) have language extensions to allow VLAs in C++, but clang's behavior is standard-conforming.

You can work around the problem with a class (or class template) that does the address translation for you, such as

```
// This is very rudimentary, but it's a point to start.
template<typename T>
class array2d_ref {
  public:
    array2d_ref(T *p, std::size_t dim) : data_(p), dim_(dim) { }

    T *operator[](std::size_t i) { return &data_[i * dim_]; }

  private:
    T *data_;
    std::size_t dim_;
};

...

array2d_ref<int> array(twoDArrayPtr, dim2);
```

But I'm afraid it is not possible (portably) to have a pointer-to-array unless you know the dimension of the array at compile time.

Comment: Will you update your code example?  I believe it should have an assignment in the constructor.  Possibly `data_=p`?

Comment: The `data_(p)` in the constructor init list does what the assignment would.

Comment: It's what I get for just typing things into the page, I guess. It works as advertised now, and it'll do the basic `arr[foo][bar]` indexing. If you need more complex pointer arithmetic, that can be emulated in roughly the same way with more proxy classes, but it'd be quite a bit of work for something that most people who read your code would understand better if you had worked with a plain `int*`. You have to decide whether it's worth the trouble. And the real fun starts if you want more than two dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, I used almost exactly this code and it is working great!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use C99's Variable Length Array(VLA) feature when you use `dim2` as the array dimension in your cast. (gcc, for example does support this by extension: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html.)

Good news, you can't do this now but you will be able to soon with the introduction of [C++14's Runtime Sized Arrays](http://blog.smartbear.com/development/a-glimpse-into-c14/).

Pertainant quotes:

> Runtime-sized arrays offer the same syntax and performance of C99’s VLAs... Bear in mind that runtime-sized arrays aren’t precisely the same as C99’s VLAs. The C++14 feature is more restrained, which is just as well. Specifically, the following properties are excluded:
>
> - Runtime-sized multidimensional arrays
> - Modifications to the function declarator syntax
> - `sizeof(a)` being a runtime-evaluated expression returning the size of a
> - `typedef int a[n];` evaluating `n` and passing it through the `typedef`

So you're code *will* be legal soon, circa C++14.

I've tried it out on the Visual Studio 2015 Beta and sadly at time of writing it is not supported :(

Comment: AFAIK `dynarray`s didn't make it to c++14 after all

Comment: @bolov Runtime Sized Arrays are different from `std::dynarray`.

Comment: @bolov Interesting I did more research and it looks like `std::dynarray` and Runtime Sized Arrays were scheduled to be released as part of `std::experimental` as of the end of 2014: http://isocpp.org/std/status The Array Extensions Technical Specification has an ISO number, but is listed as "in development": http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental

Answer (score 0):

Although clang does not support variable-length arrays, there is a workaround.  The following compiles with clang++ 4.0.0:

```
void fcn(int *twoDArrayPtr, const int dim1, const int dim2) {
    using array_type = int (*)[dim2];
    array_type array = reinterpret_cast<array_type>(twoDArrayPtr);
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure why this alias declaration should make any difference.  It certainly seems inconsistent.