# program crashes on certain inputs

Tags: c++

I have tried writing this code to output an odd-order magic square based on user input of an odd number. When I enter 1 or 3, it works fine. Whenever I enter anything above that such as 5, 7, 9, 11, etc the program crashes the moment I press enter. I've reviewed my code and I can't pinpoint where the problem is. I get no error messages.

Small note: if you know what a magic square is, my algorithm here (given to us by the professor in English to translate to C++) does not output the correct values since they don't all add up to the same number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
int n; //n = order
cout << "Enter an odd integer for the order of the Magic Square: ";
cin >> n;
cout << endl;
if(n%2 == 0)    //only allows program to accept odd numbers
    {
    cout << "The number you have entered is not odd" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
int x, y; //x and y access the columns and rows of the following matrix
int magicsquare[n][n];  //creates a n by n matrix to set up magic square
int counter, square = n*n; //square is upper boundary

for(x=0; x<n; x++)      //initialize all spaces in matrix with zeros
{
    for(y=0; y<n; y++)
        magicsquare[x][y] = 0;
}

/*Beginning of the magic square algorithm*/
x = 0, y = n/2; //initialize algorithm at the middle column of the top row
for (counter = 1; counter <= square; counter++)    //magic square will contain the integers from 1 to n squared
{
    magicsquare[x][y] = counter;    //places current counter number at current position in the matrix or square
    x--;    //moves position diagonally up
    y++;    //and to the right

    /*If a move takes you above the top row in the jth column, move to the bottom of the jth column*/
    if(x<0)
        x = n - 1;
    /*If a move takes you outside to the right of the square in the ith row, move to the left side of the ith row*/
    else if(y==n)
        y = 0;
    /*If a move takes you to an already filled square or if you move out of the square at the upper right
    hand corner, move immediately below position of previous number*/
    else if((magicsquare[x][y] != 0) || (x<0 && y==n))
    {
        y--;    //move one space to the left back into the square
        x = x+2;    //move two spots down into the square and below previous number
    }
}
for(x=0; x<n; x++)
{
    for(y=0; y<n; y++)
        cout << setw(5) << magicsquare[x][y];
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Posting a large block of code and saying it "crashes" isn't helpful. What exactly happens? Do you get an error message? What? And can you use a debugger or use print statements to at least isolate where abouts it is failing?

Comment: Have you stepped through in your debugger to see what's happening?  What kind of exception are you getting?

Comment: @MarkLuna it's unclear what you intend but the fact that you are using `else if`s in your loop to test against conditions that have already been weeded out indicates something in the logic is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I can't follow the logic in my head to know if this can ever actually happen, but in this code:

```
if(x<0)
    x = n - 1;
/*If a move takes you outside to the right of the square in the ith row, move to the left side of the ith row*/
else if(y==n)
    y = 0;
```

If *both* conditions would have been true, you won't fix up `y` and the next iteration you'll run off the end of the matrix.

Also note that `int magicsquare[n][n];` is a compiler extension and not supported by the C++ standard, since `n` is not a compile time constant. You almost certainly want to use `vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The following is illegal:

```
int magicsquare[n][n];
```

Did you ignore errors, or are you using a compiler that doesn't give errors at all? I suggest you to use an IDE that hints you when a mistake is made, so you can easily see your mistake. Please do not use notepad to write C++, that is horrible.

Fixed version:

```
int** magicsquare = new int*[n]; //creates a n by n matrix to set up magic square
for(int i = 0; i < n+1; ++i)
    magicsquare[i] = new int[n];
```

Now, together with Mark B's hint, you will get this running up in no time.
Do not forget to cleanup magicsquare by the way using delete.

Comment: Actually g++ supports this by extension. because it is allowable C99 behavior. And with the advent of the Array Extensions Technical Specification we can all use this behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28094952/2642059

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks and it doesn't give me any errors. It was working absolutely fine before so I don't know what I did that caused it to start crashing. I didn't think arrays and matrices would be declared differently from C as this is the first time I try this with C++.

Comment: Would I access the matrix the same way I access it in my code right now if I declare it as you have shown? i.e. using magicsquare[row][column]

Answer (score 0):

So I don't really know anything about magic squares. But I think that this is the behavior that you are trying to achieve:

```
for (int counter = 1, x = 0, y = (n / 2); counter <= n * n; ++counter){
    magicsquare[x][y] = counter;    //places current counter number at current position in the matrix or square

    if (counter % n == 0){ //moves down into the square and below previous number
        x = (x + 1) % n;
    }
    else //moves position diagonally up and to the right
    {
        x = (x + n - 1) % n;
        y = (y + 1) % n;
    }
}
```

Two additional points:

1. Until we can use the Array Extensions Technical Specification I think you should avoid declaring C99's runtime-sized arrays in your code. Even though gcc will allow it. You might look into doing something like: `vector<vector<int>> magicsquare(n, vector<int>(n));`
2. This doesn't match the behavior illustrated by [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square) but you can get there by tweaking the start values and order of indexing.