# Detect common base class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, introspection, base-class

Suppose one has a class hierarchy, without multiple inheritance:

```
struct TOP{};
struct L : TOP{}; 
struct R : TOP{};
struct LL : L{};
struct LR : L{};
struct RL : R{};
struct RR : R{};
```

**Is it possible to write a metafunction that will return the type of the common base of two types? (it could return `void` if not common base class exists.)**
For example

```
common_base<RR, R>::type == R
common_base<RL, RR>::type == R
common_base<LL, RR>::type == TOP
common_base<LL, std::string>::type == void
```

Obviously this wouldn't work with multiple inhertance, but I am focused in the the single inheritance case.

First, it doesn't seem to be possible without some introspection of the base class. So, I have this easier problem, do it in such a way that each clase knows its base (by an internal `base` type), for example:

```
struct LR : L{using base = L;};
```

Even in this way, I cannot seem to get the metaprogramming right.

*Also I read somewhere (I can't find it now) that GCC has some extensions to detect common base class. Is that the case?*

Comment: Would `common_base<RR, RR>::type` be `RR` or `R`?

Comment: @JamesRoot, `RR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was at some point [bases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435001/what-is-the-status-of-n2965-stdbases-and-stddirect-bases) and `direct_bases` in std::tr2 [but that wasn't included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435001/what-is-the-status-of-n2965-stdbases-and-stddirect-bases). Some versions of gcc have it. Using these perhaps you can get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I get an error just by using `#include<tr2/type_traits>` (...`6.3.1/tr2/type_traits:90:45: fatal error: '_Tp' does not refer to a value
      typedef __reflection_typelist<__bases(_Tp)...>            type;`)

Comment: @alfC You'll probably have better luck if you downgrade to gcc 4.8.0 or something like that.

Comment: I guess `tr2/type_traits` is broken (not maintained).

Comment: @alfC I don't know details, but IMO it's something that was in progress, what made into std is now in `std`, what was abandoned is now obsolete.

Comment: After a few years of thinking I got the conclusion that this lacking feature should be integrated with `std::common_type` and at the pointer level, such that `std::common_type_t<Derived1*, Derived2*>` is `Base*` when possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you have each class alias the base as `base` (like below), it can be done.

```
struct Child : Parent { using base = Parent; }; //typedef works too
```

I created a `struct`:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
struct CommonBase;
```

`CommonBase` works by comparing every base of `T2` to `T1`. When it reaches the top level base, it starts at the bottom again, but compares against the base of `T1`.

For example: `CommonBase<RL, RR>` would go through the following checks:

```
RL !=  RR
RL !=  R
RL !=  Top
R  !=  RR
R  ==  R
```

So `CommonBase<RL, RR>::type == R`. If there is no common base, `type == void`.

I put the code at the end because template metaprogramming is so pretty:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct GetBase //type = T::base, or else void
{
    template <class TT> static typename TT::base& f(int);
    template <class TT> static void f(...);
    typedef std::remove_reference_t<decltype(f<T>(0))> type;
};

template <class T1, class T2>
struct Compare2 //Compares T1 to every base of T2
{
    typedef typename GetBase<T2>::type _type;
    template <class T, bool = !std::is_same<T, void>::value>
    struct helper
    {
        typedef typename Compare2<T1, T>::type type;
    };
    template <class T>
    struct helper<T, false>
    {
        typedef void type;
    };
    typedef typename helper<_type>::type type;
};

template <class T>
struct Compare2<T, T>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <class T1, class T2>
struct Compare1 //Uses Compare2 against every base of T1
{
    typedef typename GetBase<T1>::type _type;
    template <class T, bool = !std::is_same<T, void>::value>
    struct helper
    {
        typedef typename Compare1<T, T2>::type type;
    };
    template <class T>
    struct helper<T, false>
    {
        typedef void type;
    };
    typedef std::conditional_t<std::is_same<typename Compare2<T1, T2>::type, void>::value, typename helper<_type>::type, typename Compare2<T1, T2>::type> type;
};

template <class T>
struct Compare1<T, T> //Probably redundant
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <class T1, class T2>
struct CommonBase //You can throw a std::enable_if on this to limit it to class types
{
    typedef typename Compare1<T1, T2>::type type;
};
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4bb62d1517cc2f8) you can see it on some test cases.