# C++: get superclasses type index from type index

Tags: c++, templates, reflection, superclass

I have a template type `T`, that subclasses `Base` (must not be directly).
By using

`std::type_index(typeid(T))`,

I can get a metadata object for `T`. Is there a way to get a `std::type_index` for every superclass of `T`, so that I can traverse the superclasses upwards until `Base` is reached?

I know C++ doesn't provide reflection by itself, but maybe someone knows some template magic.

In detail: I want to put pointers of objects into a map, indexed by the objects type. It would be nice to be able to insert the objects not just as their own type, but as their supertypes, too.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for something like std::bases which is not supported in c++ standard but is implemented in gcc (you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18435001/3810168)).