# Status of std::bases and std::direct_bases

Tags: c++

This is a follow-up question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435001/what-is-the-status-of-n2965-stdbases-and-stddirect-bases) 5-year-old question.

N2965 was a proposal from 2009, rejected in 2011.

Is there any news about `std::bases` and `std::direct_bases`? Will we have some functionality like this? Or is this idea completely abandoned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original proposal for `std::bases` was rejected, in part because it arrived too late for a then immediately upcoming new standard. Seems like that specific proposal has not resurfaced again.

However, there is a new and more general proposal [P0194 Static reflection](https://wg21.link/P0194) that includes ways to not only interrogate  base classes, but also has a much wider target.

Right now, that proposal contains some types that seems to do something like what the `std::bases` proposal suggested:

```
template <Class T> struct get_public_base_classes;
template <Class T> struct get_accessible_base_classes;
template <Class T> struct get_base_classes;
```

---

However (again), in Herb Sutter's [latest report from the ISO C++ meeting](https://herbsutter.com/2018/07/02/trip-report-summer-iso-c-standards-meeting-rapperswil/) he projects these kinds of features not to appear in C++20, but perhaps in a future C++23 standard.

[image]