# Cascade calls on override virtual methods

Tags: c++, design-patterns, super, anti-patterns

I'm working on a large software, that heavily relies on the call super anti-pattern.

Basically, an interface defines an `init()` virtual method that is then overridden in every classes that inherits it.
When `init()` is called on the class, EVERY overloaded `init` methods are cascaded, from the base class to the top daughter class, and all in between.

But the user HAS to call its direct parent's `init()` method in its own, which results in code like this:

```
class myClass : public Base
{
    virtual void init()
    {
        Parent::Init() // often forgotten, or misplaced by the developer
        // Do some init stuff
    }
}
```

An alternative to this is usually to use delegates. The Base class has stuff to do in `init`, that is declared `final` in Base, and delegates part of it to an `onInit()` method that inheriting classes should override. But this does not cascade the calls to all parent classes as I'd like it to.

The alternative I've first implemented is a variant of the delegate approach. Both daughter classes and Base implement a `onInit()` and a `init()` method. 
`init()` calls `Parent::init()` followed by a call to `onInit()` on itself, and is auto-generated using template meta-programming & macros.
and `onInit()` contains the class-specific code.

```
# define DELEGATE(T, Parent) \
     void init() override { Parent::init(); T::onInit(); }

struct Base
{
    virtual void init() { Base::onInit(); }
    virtual void onInit() {}
};

struct A : public Base
{
     DELEGATE(A, Base)
     void onInit() override { /* MyCustom code for A */ }
};

struct B : public A
{
     DELEGATE(B, A)
     void onInit() override { /* MyCustom code for B */ }
};
```

This works pretty well.. except that multiple inheritance becomes a mess, and even if handled, diamond inheritance causes issues with duplicated calls.

Which leaves me wondering: I can't be the only person looking for a design pattern solving my issue, and the stackoverflow community must know about it :)

Have you ever encountered a design pattern for this?
I'm really looking forward to your ideas!

Comment: I don't get it. Doesn't this actually call the derived class's `onInit` twice? Once from `Base`'s `init`, and once from the expansion of the `DELEGATE` macro.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Base::init() should call Base::onInit() insteead on onInit() I fixed my post, sorry for that

Comment: You might use CRTP, instead of MACRO (and so handle easily multiple inheritance).

Comment: For duplicated calls, you might pass a `std::set<std::type_index>` to conditionally call `onInit`.

Comment: Unfortunately, [proposal for `std::bases` and `std::direct_bases`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435001/what-is-the-status-of-n2965-stdbases-and-stddirect-bases) has been rejected.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would to protect yourself from forgetting about overriding in children classes. This is simple template method design pattern implementation:

```
class Base {
public:
    void init() {
        //base init steps
        childInit();
    }

private:
    virtual void childInit() = 0;
};

class Child : public Base {
private:
    void childInit() override { /*init the child*/}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @bartop but this won't do for me, as I want all the childs, and the child's childs to get their init() method called in a cascade. If I had a class A inheriting Base, a class B inheriting A and a class C inheriting B for instance, I'd want a call to init() on C to perform the following calls:
Base::init(); A::init(): B::init(); C::init()