# Expose the most direct base class template name

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++17, multiple-inheritance

Consider the following code:

```
template <class...> struct base {};
template <class... T> struct intermediate: base<void, T...> {};
template <class... T> struct derived: base<T...>, intermediate<T...> {};

using type1 = derived<int>::intermediate::base; // works
using type2 = derived<int>::base; // ambiguous
```

Would there be a way to make it work without ambiguity so that `derived<int>::base` means the most "direct" base class in the hierarchy (in this example `base<int>`). Template metaprogramming is welcomed.

Comment: Could you change to `struct derived: wrapped<base<T...>>, intermediate<T...> {};`?

Comment: Yes. I can change the hierachy as long as I can type `derived<int>::base` and `derived<int>::intermediate::base`

Comment: It would do `derived<int>::wrapped::base`, `derived<int>::intermediate::base`... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If appropriate, you might add alias in `derived`, so you can use them from outside:

```
template <class... Ts> struct derived: base<Ts...>, intermediate<Ts...>
{
    using DirectBase = base<Ts...>;
    using IndirectBase = typename intermediate<Ts...>::base;
};
```

And then

```
using type1 = derived<int>::IndirectBase ;
using type2 = derived<int>::DirectBase ;
```

I see no ways to disambiguate.

There was [proposal for `std::bases` `std::direct_bases`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435001/what-is-the-status-of-n2965-stdbases-and-stddirect-bases) which might help, but rejected.

Comment: Unfortunately, I would like to keep the same name (in my real case, base might be a template template, and I would like to keep the same same, whatever it is)

Comment: You cannot do `using base = base<Ts...>;` neither :-/

Comment: Normally indirect base is a base class of base class, not a "co-parent"