# Trait to get base class(es) of given class in compile time

Tags: c++, c++11

In cpp I can easily check if class `A` is subclass of `B` like that:

```
class B{};
class A : public B {};

is_base_of_v<B, A>
```

But is there a way to do something like this?

```
class B{};
class C{};
class A : public B, public C {};

using bases  = base_classes<A>; //giving tuple<B, C> or something like that
```

Comment: [what-is-the-status-of-n2965-stdbases-and-stddirect-bases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435001/what-is-the-status-of-n2965-stdbases-and-stddirect-bases)

Comment: Pretty sure this can't be done with "stock" c++.  Maybe when we get reflection.