# Deducing a shared base of two classes in C++

Tags: c++, type-traits, c++-experimental

I am almost certain that what I'm looking for cannot be done without *reflection*, which is not yet in the language. But occasionally I'm getting surprised with exceptional answers in SO, so let's try.

Is it possible to deduce the "common_base" of two types that have a common shared base class, so the following would be possible (pseudo code! -- **there is no** `common_base_t` **in the language**, this is the *magic* I'm trying to achieve):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
const common_base_t<T1, T2>& foo(const T1& a1, const T2& a2) {
    if(a1 < a2) return a1;
    return a2;
}
```

Note that `a1` and `a2` above do not share a `common_type`, just by being siblings (sharing the same base) thus we cannot use the ternary operator.

Note also that changing the above return type to `const auto&` doesn't do the trick (it would not compile: *inconsistent deduction for auto return type*).

Here is a the naïve implementation, requiring the caller to state the expected return type:

```
template<typename R>
const R& foo(const auto& a1, const auto& a2) {
    if(a1 < a2) return a1;
    return a2;
}
```

Then we can call it with:

```
MyString1 s1 = "hello"; // MyString1 derives from std::string
MyString2 s2 = "world"; // MyString2 also derives from std::string
std::cout << foo<std::string>(s1, s2); // ok we return const lvalue ref
                                       // pointing to one of the above objects
```

There are many reasons for why this *probably* cannot be achieved without providing the expected return value. But maybe it could be achieved *somehow*?

Comment: What if they have multiple shared bases? What would you expect the return type of the function to be then?

Comment: @Frank it can be evaluated to "no type" in such cases (i.e. fail to compile) - I'm OK with that. This is of course one of the arguments for not having such a thing in the language (hard to define our expectations) - but still: can it be implemented for the simple cases where there are no multiple shared bases?

Comment: @Frank It should return the most derived common type. But what if you have diamond patterns in the inheritance? Both sides of the diamond could be a common type what then?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow No need for a diamond pattern to cause ambiguity, for example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WEnd36M3f

Comment: You should add a `MyString1::base_type` and `MyString2::base_type` manually and then you can use that as return type and `requires` that they are the same.

Comment: @Frank I see that as a special diamond pattern where the common root is `void`, kind of. But yeah, any multiple inheritance can screw this up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get base class for a type in class hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262338/get-base-class-for-a-type-in-class-hierarchy)

Comment: @StackDanny a solution with `std::tr2::bases` can be an answer, the link that you point at presents the tool but not an entire solution. I'm not asking anybody to invest time especially for that, but maybe someone already implemented it?

Comment: looks like a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65619415/can-c-templates-provide-the-common-parent-class-of-n-given-classes

Comment: somewhat related, interesting discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49240345/2805305

Comment: @bolov very good links! Both are related, one may even be considered as a dup, but I believe the question as is (and the great answers) still deserve the discussion that it raised here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library's [`std::common_reference<>`](https://cppreference.fasanowood.com/en/cpp/types/common_reference.html) is tantalizingly close to what you want, and arguably what your `foo()` function should be using, as it clearly expresses the desired semantics:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::common_reference_t<const T1&, const T2&> foo(const T1& a1, const T2& a2) {
    if(a1 < a2) return a1;
    return a2;
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work out of the box for this specific use-case, as it cannot detect common bases unless one of the types derives from the other.

However, you can give it a hint by specializing [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type). Like so:

```
namespace std {
    template<>
    struct common_type<MyString1, MyString2> {
        using type = std::string;
    };
}
```

And it will "just work". You can see it in action here:  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e3PrecPac.

**Edit:**
It's worth mentioning that, depending on your circumstances, you could also create a general purpose specialization of `std::common_type` for all types that derive from a given base:

```
struct SomeBase {};

namespace std {
    template<std::derived_from<SomeBase> T1, std::derived_from<SomeBase> T2>
    struct common_type<T1, T2> {
        using type = SomeBase;
    };
}
```

However, I would thread lightly with this. It's a potentially very broad and wide-ranging partial specialization. It could easily lead to ambiguities, especially if done more than once.

Comment: I would also venture that if a clean way to automatically detect common bases was added to the language, then `common_reference_t` would most likely be updated to automatically make use of it, making this approach "ready for the future".

Comment: I like this approach. Would just note that there is a need to specialize the `common_type` for MyString1 and MyString2 twice, per each direction: https://godbolt.org/z/dfdnW417v

Answer (score 3):

I can think of three approaches.

#1 is waiting for/using reflection.

#2 is using `std::tr2::direct_bases` and `std::tr2::bases` from way back.  This is going to be a pain if you want to be able to handle "the common base is not the direct base, nor is it unique".

Doing this requires a metaprogramming library, and you end up with something like:

```
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
struct common_base< Lhs, Rhs,
  std::enable_if_t< always_true< extract_if_unique_t<common_direct_bases_t<Lhs, Rhs>> > >
> {
  using type = extract_if_unique_t<common_direct_bases_t<Lhs, Rhs>>;
};
```

and it gets complex, with writing a bunch of metaprogramming boilerplate.

#3 is providing a canonical list of bases you are looking for as common bases, and searching for them as possible bases of your types.  Often this is a good idea, as it means uninvolved implementation detail types don't derail you (the open-closed principle).

For the last one, I'd just do a `is_base_of` filter on the list of canonical bases in order for both types, then grab the first one in both lists.

```
template<template<class...>class Op, class List>
struct filter;
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
struct intersect_lists;
template<class List>
struct front;

template<class...>
struct types {};

using canonical_bases = types<A,B,C,D>; // in order

template<class Derived>
struct BaseTest {
  template<class Base>
  using result = std::is_base_of_t< Base, Derived >;
};

template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
using canonical_common_base_of = 
  front_t< intersect_lists_t<
    filter_t<BaseTest<Lhs>::template result, canonical_bases>,
    filter_t<BaseTest<Rhs>::template result, canonical_bases>
  >>;
```

with another few dozen lines of metaprogramming (or use an existing metaprogramming to reproduce something equivalent).

Comment: Here's an implementation of #3 that doesn't need any fancy metaprogramming primitives: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dzzd8x8rb

Comment: Above is a very good answer, however the approach of implementing std::common_type for my user defined types, proposed in Frank's answer, better fits my need - I'm accepting that one. At the same time others may find above answer better for their own needs.