# Check whether two classes have a common base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-traits

In [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72383571/deducing-a-shared-base-of-two-classes-in-c) the *desire* for something like `common_base_t` was raised. It is true that the result might be ambiguous, as two classes may have more than a single shared base class.

I'm looking for a way to discover whether two classes have a shared common base, just yes or no, without asking who is this shared base.

Again I feel that this cannot be achieved with the current tools that we have in C++20 (and including the expected tools in C++23). However, maybe someone may have an idea. Using Boost or any other external library is acceptable, but **not** something that is not supported in the language, like the old `std::tr2`.

I have failed, [trying to implement](https://godbolt.org/z/GvabYG11P) (naively I'd say) something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
concept have_common_public_base =
    std::derived_from<T, std::common_type_t<T, Ts...>> &&
    (std::derived_from<Ts, std::common_type_t<T, Ts...>> && ...);
```

As `std::common_type` doesn't see the common type of two distinct classes, even if they share a common base (unless one actually derives publicly from the other, directly or indirectly, which is a simple case not covering the general case).

Any idea? Maybe some magic games with `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: Why do you need this? How is it useful? Imagine someone reimplementing Java library classes in C++. Everything in their world derives from `Object` so the answer is always "yes". What next?